# Access to subquery value in joined inner subquery

Tags: sql, clickhouse

`LEFT JOIN` should implement `FOR EACH` date in my case without using procedures

```
SELECT * FROM
    (   
        SELECT DISTINCT(toDate(date_update)) as dist_date
        FROM prod.point_pg pp
    )Q1
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT sum(Q2.lockers_count), max(lockers_date) as l_date FROM
        (
            SELECT count(pg.id) as lockers_count, toDate(pg.date_update) as lockers_date FROM prod.point_pg pg
            WHERE pg.state=0 and pg.publish=TRUE
            GROUP BY toDate(pg.date_update) 
        )Q2
    WHERE Q2.lockers_date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND Q1.dist_date
    )Q3
ON Q1.dist_date = Q3.l_date
```

But subquery Q2 can't acccess to first table variable Q1

```
    SQL Error [47] [07000]: Code: 47. DB::Exception: 
Missing columns: 'Q1.dist_date' while processing query:
```

How it is possible to access to dist_date then? Final result should contain each date and sum of counters between start date and dist_date but I need a value for range in `WHERE` statement

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ used to get distinct _rows_. Simply write `SELECT DISTINCT toDate(date_update) as...` to make code clearer.

Comment: What happens if you move the final WHERE clause out of the subquery? (To the ON clause.)

Comment: @jarlh, Exception: Missing columns: 'Q2.lockers_date'  still no access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this query can much simpler, but without create_table/insert/expected result it's unclear.

you cannot address `dist_date` inside the subquery, only outside:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
    (   
        SELECT DISTINCT(toDate(date_update)) as dist_date
        FROM prod.point_pg pp
    )Q1
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT sum(Q2.lockers_count), max(lockers_date) as l_date FROM
        (
            SELECT count(pg.id) as lockers_count, toDate(pg.date_update) as lockers_date FROM prod.point_pg pg
            WHERE pg.state=0 and pg.publish=TRUE
            GROUP BY toDate(pg.date_update) 
        )Q2
    WHERE Q2.lockers_date >= '2023-01-01'
    )Q3
ON Q1.dist_date = Q3.l_date

WHERE Q2.lockers_date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND Q1.dist_date
```

Comment: This query returns Q3 result only for one date. Tried that too.

Comment: I don't understand. without create_table/insert/expected result it's unclear.

Comment: You are right. The only approach is to create tables in case of Clickhouse, because for MySQL or Postgres I would use stored procedure. Thank you all for help and advices, my co-worker and I decided to use Airflow since such cases can't be done with only strict SQL queries.